# findAssocs (tm) returns all correlations as a list of ones

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, data-science

I have a corpus created from 2 text documents and a DocumentTermMatrix of which I want to find correlations between words. Whatever choice of words I select the `findAssocs` function returns correlations = 1 for all  words in the corpus. Why is that?

Here are excerpts from my code:

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
doc <- Corpus(DirSource("C:/Users/biat/Documents/customersatis"))

toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x,pattern) {return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})

doc <- tm_map(doc, toSpace, "-")
doc <- tm_map(doc, toSpace, ":")
doc <- tm_map(doc, removePunctuation)
doc <- tm_map(doc,content_transformer(tolower))
doc <- tm_map(doc,removeNumbers)
doc <- tm_map(doc,removeWords,stopwords("swedish"))
doc <- tm_map(doc,stripWhitespace)
doc <- tm_map(doc, PlainTextDocument)
doc <- tm_map(doc, stemDocument, "swedish")

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(doc)
findAssocs(dtm,"active",0.1)
```

When I run this the results imply that the term "active" is correlated to all 560 other words by 1 as follows which in reality it's not.

```
$active
  admin    actions    all   analysis arrends   
      1          1      1          1       1 .........    
   ...................................................        

............................ website  workshops  
                                   1          1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: You have two documents in your corpus. Any two words that are found in both documents will have a correlation of one. My guess would be that your documents are very similar, although without a reproducible example, it is impossible to know what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by scoa you might have two documents in which a term happens both times: resulting in ones.

Try collapsing the document before turning it into a corpus:

```
text <- paste(unlist(text), collapse ="")
```